# How to start an LXC container inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, lxc

How do I start a LXC container inside of a docker container - end to end - with shared networking? Ideally I'd like to do this with Debian or Ubuntu. Some problems I found when trying to do this:

- lxc-net doesn't start when installed into a Docker container, so the `lxcbr0` bridge never gets created. Partial workaround is to manually create the bridge.
- lxc containers fail to start to due to `cgroupfs failed to detect cgroup metadata`, even if I manually mount a cgroup via `mount -n -t tmpfs -o uid=0,gid=0,mode=0755 cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup`

Comment: Did you try resolving this issue? I am facing the same issue :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way how to run LXD inside Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43741660/is-there-a-way-how-to-run-lxd-inside-docker)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `--privileged` flag to your docker [container docs](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-linux-capabilities-and-lxc-configuration)

Comment: Done that. Just booting a docker container, installing LXC, and trying to start some LXC containers yields various problems though. That's why I posted the question.

Comment: If you boot an ubuntu container, install lxc and dnsmasq, lxc-net never runs even though the upstart config is in place. Attempting to run it via `service lxc-net start` yields `lxc-net: unrecognized service`. Not sure why. lxc-net installs and starts fine on a bare metal machine.